# How to use relative path to reference json schema when exporting to Json?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report as simple as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testJsonExportWithSchema" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f59243f1-8df7-4c2a-b075-3ca20c4b17f2">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.schema" value="schema.json"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="63" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="63" uuid="7801126d-70f5-4d0c-9c19-3588dc5fce40">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="key"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["value"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And would like to export it to Json using below Json schema:

```
{
    _type: 'object',
    key: 'value'
}
```

Using a relative path to schema (as I do with subreports, images and other resources on the same folder):

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.schema" value="schema.json"/>`

I get this:

`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at: schema.json`

If I use absolute path it works fine:

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.schema" value="c:\users\username\path\to\schema.json"/>`

This need for an absolute path is preventing me from using Json schemas in JasperReports Server too.

Comment: I would like to upload a minimal working example, but I don't know where.

Comment: Hi if it can fit in post it's not minimal :), anyway can't you use `repo://` in your path?

Comment: or pass the path in parameter and then use `<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.schema"><![CDATA[$P{Path}]]></propertyExpression>`

Comment: repo:/ doesn't work with server. Asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366885/how-to-export-server-report-to-json-using-json-schema). I guess nobody cares about exporting to Json, only using Json as datasource.

Comment: :(, well yeah it's not the most common use and unfortunately I have from no to little experience, however it would be nice for SO if you manage to find an answer, have you tried to pass as parameter

Comment: Passing a parameter whose value is the absolute path works the same way as putting the absolute path string. Basically the schema can't live as a resource on your server. It must be in the file system, which is very annoying and difficult to maintain.

Comment: What I mean is that in this way in application you  can have relative path (or property) and the let BE convert the relative path to an absolute path.

Comment: Don't know if I get. What is BE? What I would like is not having to change anything from my development report to the one I upload to Jasper Server.

Comment: BE = Backend, the code that execute the report, but maybe in your case you do not have such application, personally I don't use the jasper server, so I can send any parameters through in BE. If you don't have BE you could included a class (.jar) that returns the absolute path hence a method with something like `public static String MyLookup.getAbsoultePath(String relativePath);` then instead of using $P in  property expression you call this method with your relative path.